# ¿Como se puede ver las veces que se repite un elemento de una cadena?

Tags: c

```
uint8 GENFUN_u8GetOccurence (uint8 *pu8Src, uint8 u8Target, uint8 u8SizeOfList)
```

**Parámetros:**

- pu8Src: Apuntador que recibe la dirección de la cadena.
- u8Target: Elemento a buscar en la cadena.
- u8SizeOfList: Número de elementos de la cadena.

**Retorno:** El número de ocurrencias en la cadena.

La función deberá recibir una cadena con N elementos y un Target a buscar, devolverá el número de veces que Target se repite en la misma.

Comment: Que tienes hecho hasta ahora?? Te invito a [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Y esto que es? Nos estas contando de esta funcion? Nos estas pidiendo que la implementemos? Que onda?

Comment: que se implemente un apuntador el cual determine utlizando u8SizeOfList  el numero de veces que una variable se repita dentro de la cadena, dando como output el numero de veces que la variable se repitio

Comment: @Morog89 debes mostrar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). De lo contrario, la pregunta terminará cerrada.